# Ordered DAG traversal

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG that represents multiple arbitrary boolean expressions. DAG consists of two types of the nodes:

1. Leaf node (predicate that consists of attribute, operator, value(s))
2. Intermediate node (AND/OR)

Each node in the graph can be reused in other expressions as subexpression.

[image]

To compute an `OR`/`AND` node for example, it's predicates must be computed first (or intermediate nodes).

Is there any optimal algorithm that can provide this sort of bottom-up, level-order traversal for DAG staring with predicate nodes?

Comment: Yes. The algorithm is called **topological sort**. It's implemented in pretty much every graph library, and has a wikipedia page that describes it pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `topological sort`. Let me write the pseudocode with explanations for you. The idea is that if there is a path from `u` to `v`, then `v` appears after `u` in the ordering.

In both implementations, we'll create a data structure named `output` and append the vertices one by one to it. Eventually, `output` will give us the `topological order`.

First implementation:

1. Compute the **indegrees** of all vertices.
   **indegree** of a vertex is the number of head ends adjacent to that vertex.
2. Find a vertex `u` with indegree = 0, and store it in the `output`. If there is no such vertex, then it means that graph is not **acyclic**, therefore there is no topological order.
3. Remove `u` and all its edges from the graph.
4. Update the indegrees of the remaining vertices if necessary.
5. Repeat the steps 2,3 and 4 `V` times, `V` being the number of vertices in the graph. 
   Time complexity of this implementation is `O(V^2)`.

More efficient implementation:

1. Compute the indegrees of all vertices.
2. Store all vertices with indegree 0 in an arbitrary data structure* `A` and store all vertices with positive indegree in another arbitrary data structure `B`.
3. Remove vertex `u` from the `A` and store it in `output`.
4. For all **edges** `(u, v)`, update the indegree of `v`. If indegree of `v` is 0, take it from `B` and put it to the `A`.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until `A` and `B` become empty. 
   Time complexity of this implementation is `O(V + E)`, `E` being the number of edges in the graph.

*= Any data structure that allows adding and removing in `O(1)` (constant time) will be ok.

Notice that `topological order` may not be unique. For example there is no hierarchy between `attr_2>=200` and `attr_3 IN ["yellow", "green"]` nodes in your graph. So their orders respective to each other may vary.

Comment: Your second implementation mentions only one data structure - the queue of vertices with indegree 0. But you should maintain two data structures in addition to the output list: one for vertices with indegree 0, and one for vertices with positive indegree. For instance, in step 4, "If indegree of v is 0, put it to the queue" should be "If indegree of v is 0, then remove it from the list of vertices with positive indegree, and push it to the queue".

Comment: Additionally, you specifically ask for a queue, but I don't see a particular reason for it. A queue is specifically First-In-First-Out; this doesn't appear to be needed here; any structure is suitable, ordered or unordered, as long as it supports adding and removing elements.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I've gone through my Java-implementation of the algorithm while writing the solution, that's why second part became unnecessarily specific.

Comment: Now "and store it in ordering (array, list etc.)." is so unspecific it becomes confusing; perhaps you should include the word "output" at this point. Like "and add it in the next spot of the output" or something.